# Java pooling connection optimization

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, http

Which are the commons guidelines/advices to configure, in Java, a http connection pool to support huge number of concurrent http calls to the same server? I mean:

- max total connections
- max default connection per route
- reuse strategy
- keep alive strategy
- keep alive duration
- connection timeout
- ....

(I am using Apache http components 4.3, but I am available to explore new solutions)

In order to be more clear, this is my situation:

I developed a REST resource that needs to perform about 10 http calls to AWS CloudSearch in order to obtain search results to be collected in a final result (that I really cannot obtain through a single query).
The whole operation must take less than 0.25 seconds. So, I run http calls in parallel in 10 different threads. 
During a benchamarking test, I noticed that with few concurrent request, 5, my objective is reached. But, increasing concurrent requests to 30, there is a tremendous degradation of performance due to the connection time that takes about 1 second. With few concurrent requests, instead, the connection time is about 150 ms (to be more precise, the first connection takes 1 second, all the following connections take about 150 ms). I can ensure that CloudSearch returns its response in less than 15 ms, so there is a problem somewhere in my connection pool.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The amount of threads/connections that are best for your implementation depend on that implementation (which you did not post), but here are some guidelines as requested:

- If those threads never block at all, you should have as many threads as cores (Runtime.availableCores(), this will include hyperthread-cores). Simply because more than 100% CPU usage isn't possible.
- If your threads rarely block, cores * 2 is a good start for benchmarking.
- If your threads frequently block, you absolutely need to benchmark your application with various settings to find the best solution for your implementation, OS and hardware.

Now the most optimal case is obviously the first one, but to get to this one, you need to remove blocking from your code as much as you can. Java can do this for IO operations if you use the NIO package in non-blocking mode (which is not how the Apache package does it).

Then you have 1 thread that waits on a selector and awakes as soon as any data is ready to be sent or read. This thread then only copies the data from it's source to the destination and returns to the selector. In case of a read (incoming data), this destination is a blocking queue, on which *core* amount of threads wait. One of those threads will then pull out the received data and process it, now without any blocking.

You can then use the length of the blocking queue to adjust how many parallel requests are reasonable for your task and hardware.

The first connection takes >1 second, because it actually has to look-up the address via DNS. All other connections are put on hold for the moment, as there is no sense in doing this twice. You can circumvent that by either calling the IP (probably not good if you talk to a load-balancer) or by "warming-up" the connections with an initial request. Any new connection afterwards will use the cached DNS result, but still needs to perform other initializations, so reusing connections as much as you can will reduce latency a lot. With NIO this is a very easy task.

In addition there are [HTTP-multi-requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), that is: you make one connection but request several URLs in one request and get several responses over "the same line". This massively reduces connection overhead, but needs to be supported by the server.